# Is there a faster way to download IBD for bitcoin core?

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization, bitcoin-qt-setup

I am trying to setup a node using bitcoin core https://bitcoin.org/en/bitcoin-core/
but it is taking ages to download. Running for past 2 days and downloaded only 15 % .  I have a decent internet connectivity 200 Mbps and a 4 GB windows machine with 200 GB of free disk dedicated for this.

Since the blocks get pruned, is it possible to get the latest pruned cut from somwhere I guess that will be around 2 GB instead of 350 GB .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

If you could download an already synchronized state, you shouldn’t do that. The purpose of synchronization is to produce a valid database containing the state of the network, downloading somebody else’s can have false entries and your node would not know that it is invalid. Increasing the `dbcache` can improve performance but you don’t have much additional memory to give Bitcoin Core to use.

Comment: How much memory will be ideal for this ? I downloaded testnet and it downloaded in a few hours on the same computer. But relatively main is super slow .

Comment: Generally speaking more is better, if you can allocate a gigabyte or two to the `dbcache` it will be somewhat faster, there's diminishing returns past 4GB.

Comment: I have given 2048 MB as Size of database cache, and nothing else is running besides bitcoin core. I have given Prune block storage to 2GB, do think that can cause this slowness ?